# Servlet jar not loaded Tomcat Issue

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat

I restarted tomcat today and the webapp is offline.

And when I referred catalina.out file I saw the following error.

```
Dec 27, 2012 6:38:21 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/dun/stud01/webapps/WEB-INF/lib/servlet.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

All this time before today the appliacation was working fine.
Its a Unix IBM-AIX server envirnment.

I dont know what went wrong all this time it was working fine.
Can anyone suggest how to bring back the website online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the relevant chapter of the [servlet spec](http://www.jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr053/)? It says:

> It must not allow the WAR to override J2SE or Java servlet API
>   classes.

In other words, you should **not** be providing `servlet.jar` in your webapp as it is already shipped with Tomcat. Remove it from your .war and restart Tomcat.

Comment: I dont have a war as i do a manual build.I tried removing and restarting the same error pops up.Before today I have restarted several times and its worked fine.Dont know why its causing issue now.When it was working fine the servlet.jar was in the lib directory.

Comment: Can you confirm `/dun/stud01/webapps/WEB-INF/lib/servlet.jar` does not exist after you deploy your .war?

Comment: It exists and it always existed and worked fine.BTW I have a manual build I don't have a war file.

Comment: In this case I'm afraid you are a victim of your own stubbornness. You are violating the spec and even refuse to try running Tomcat without servlet.jar, there's nothing I can help you with.

Comment: In this case do i need to delete the jar file in the foll dir:/dun/stud01/webapps/WEB-INF/lib or /opt/apache-tomcat-5.5.25/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib coz both have the jar files.

Comment: I'd say both. You also need to ensure `$tomcat_home/common/lib/servlet-api.jar` is present as it comes with the Tomcat distribution.

Comment: How can I ensure $tomcat_home/common/lib/servlet-api.jar is present??

Comment: It comes with Tomcat distribution. If you removed it, you need to download it again.

Comment: I deleted the files from both the locations and the catalina.out does not display any error messages but the site is still down.BTW I have not deleted anything related to Tomcat distribution.

Comment: It's hard to advice more without knowing more details. "Site is down" is not very verbose in order to identify what's wrong with it. If it is down because of other reason than this post, you might want to open another question and provide as much details as you can.

Comment: Thanks for the help.It was down coz of a different reason.Thanks for the tips.

Comment: @david.colais, it might be helpful for others who search and find this thread to include what the "different reason" was that caused your problem...